# Difference between commands `\setminus` and `\backslash`

Tags: formatting, symbols

Is there any difference in usage of the mentioned commands? I ask it because, for example, it's known that for functions it's more preferable (and more correct) to use `\colon` instead of usual `:`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the Computer Modern math font family, the *shapes* of `\setminus` and `\backslash` are identical. (Aside: the vertical size of `\backslash` can be modified by `\left` and `\right` directives; that's not the case for `\setminus`.) That does not mean, though, that the symbols get *typeset* identically. This is because `\backslash` has status `mathord` ("math ordinary"), whereas `\setminus` has status mathbin ("math binary operators"). Having status `mathbin` means that in combinations of mathord-mathbin-mathord -- as in `U\setminus V` -- a "medspace" amount of whitespace gets inserted on both sides of the `\setminus` symbol.

In contrast, TeX does not insert whitespace between math atoms (to use a TeX jargon word) of status `mathord`. Hence, no extra whitespace is inserted in `U\backslash V`.

Finally, mainly for the sake of completeness, it's worth mentioning the existence of the macro `\smallsetminus`, which is provided by the `amssymb` package. As one can tell from the final row of the following table, `\smallsetminus` looks rather different from `\setminus`, doesn't it?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,array,booktabs,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} >{$}l<{$} l @{}}
$Result$ & LaTeX code \\
\midrule
\setminus\mkern-9mu\color{red}\backslash & \verb+\setminus\mkern-9mu\color{red}\backslash+ \\
\addlinespace
B\setminus D            & \verb+B\setminus D+ \\
B\mathbin{\setminus}D   & \verb+B\mathbin{\setminus}D+ \\
B\:{\setminus}\:D       & \verb+B\:{\setminus}\:D+ \\
B\mkern4mu{\setminus}\mkern4mu D & \verb+B\mkern4mu{\setminus}\mkern4mu D+ \\
\addlinespace
B{\setminus}D           & \verb+B{\setminus}D+ \\
B\backslash D           & \verb+B\backslash D+ \\
\addlinespace
B\smallsetminus D      & \verb+B\smallsetminus D+ 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See my comment under the question:-) (but you could add ams \smallsetminus

Answer (score 2):

In [`unicode-math`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf), `\backslash` is \  (U+005C) , `\setminus` is ⧵ (U+29F5) and `\smallsetminus` is ∖ (U+2216).  Also, `\xbsol` is ⧹ (U+29F9).

This is especially noticeable when using the default font, Latin Modern Math, which lacks `\setminus`.  New Computer Modern Math fixes this bug.